# How to reinterpret_cast char* to a non-pod type safely?

Tags: c++

Something to the effect of:

```
 std::string s;
 char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s);   // Legal
 T* t_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(c);      // Illegal
```

I have read most of the answers here about getting a struct from char* or std::byte. It seems to me that the only standard compliant way is to memcpy into an object of the target type (std::string in this case). But that'll only work for POD types (not for std::string).

```
std::string target_string;
std::memcpy(&target_string, c, sizeof(string)); // This produces garbage for non-POD types
```

This is mostly out of academic interest, while trying to think how to implement something like std::optional. I understand that there might be other ways of achieving something similar like using a Union and keeping track of the active type. My main purpose of asking this is to see if there is a gap in my understanding here.

Comment: `memcpy` is only valid for trivial types, which `std::string` is not.

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve? What is the original and underlying problem that this should solve? Please ask about that directly instead, as there might be other (and actually working) solutions.

Comment: @NathanOliver exactly, so what can I do for std::string, since reinterpret_cast is also not guaranteed to work from char* to any type T*? Thanks.

Comment: C++ doesn't really have a way for you to take a binary buffer and create non-trivial objects out of it.  That is why *serialization* is such a big topic

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor that takes a null-terminated `char*`

Comment: *How to reinterpret_cast `char*` to a non-pod type safely?*  Safely?  By not doing that, since it will only end in tears.

Comment: Dereferencing is perfectly legal as long as `T` object is actually stored there, in this case `std::string`. `reinterpret_cast` just doesn't have the power to create an object - that is what placement new can do. If you want to magically create an object from its byte representation, you can't and you should not want that e.g. for `std::string`.

Comment: What does this have to do with implementing `std::optional`? It would have a byte array under the hood.

Comment: @Raildex Yes, but the result of `char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&s)` isn't a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Quimby could you please point me to a source for:

> Dereferencing is perfectly legal as long as T object is actually stored there,

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast
This page doesn't seem to mention any such thing, but I have never seen the implementation you suggested break either (in my toy examples).

Comment: @AbhishekKumar see "Type aliasing" section https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: By using `std::memcpy()` you're bypassing the `std::string` copy constructor which would safely copy the string. Without it, you're only copying the pointer (for example) to the single heap address of the string content. When both strings go out of scope, their destructors will attempt to free the same heap memory. This is just an example for std::string, but all non-POD types share a similar risk.

Comment: @Quimby in this AliasedType would be string and DyanamicType would be char, based on the language on that page. Please feel free to correct me if I am missing something here, but isn't what the reference says only holds for other way round (converting string* to char*).

Comment: `DynamicType` is the type of the *object* actually stored at that address, `AliasedType` is the type through which you are trying to access that *object*. So it works regardless of direction. `reinterpret_cast` is the way how to obtain the `AliasedType`. So the first is is legal because `char*` can be used to access any `DynamicType` as per rules. Second cast for `T==std::string` is also legal because you are using `std::string` to access `std::string` object, of course that must be allowed.

Comment: @JaMiT That speaks about the pointer value itself, not the value behind that pointer. The converted pointers do not have to be equal, this guarantees that inequality is reversible.

Comment: Thanks @Quimby and JaMiT for helping me interpret the doc. It does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are casting a pointer to `std::string` to a pointer to another type `T`. I'm not sure what kind of result you expect from that.

If you're wondering about an `std::optional` implementation, the idea is to have a buffer of bytes large enough to hold a type `T`, while also satisfying the alignment requirements of `T`. You can then reinterpret a pointer to that buffer as a pointer to `T`. However, you need to treat it as a proper C++ type, that is *not* using `memcpy` and instead using placement `new` and manual destruction at the end.

```cpp
class T { ... };

...
/* A buffer of same size and alignment as T */
alignas(alignof(T)) std::byte buff[sizeof(T)];

/* Manually call T's constructor */
new(buff) T(...);
T& obj1 = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff);

/* Now you can use buff as a T */
obj1.some_function(...);
T obj2 = obj1;
...

/* When done, manually call the destructor */
obj1.~T();
```

Comment: I agree with your implementation. I just wasn't sure if this line is kosher:
`T& obj1 = *reinterpret_cast<T*>(buff);


From the discussion it seems like it is.